# Corrupted file on external hard drive

Tags: finder, hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk, storage

I have installed a file onto my external hard drive, since then my external hard drive has dramatically slow down and files takes too long to load or open (the external drive is not useable anymore). I have tried to transfer the files that are on the external drive to my Mac so I could format the external drive but finder keeps crashing while transferring my files on the same spot around 217 MB. I was wondering if there is a way to see why Finder crashes? Also is there a way to fix the external drive? I assume it's a corrupted file that has not been deleted properly but I am not too sure

I tried to run tried to fix the external drive using the First Aid in Disk Utility but when I do %95 of the time I get an error "Unable to unmount volume for repair. : (-69673)" and sometimes it passes the First Aid fix (after I restart my Mac and replug the external drive over and over) but don't seem to fix the problem.
I have also uninstalled the WD discovery and WD Drive Utilities softwares but nothing seem to change.

I run Mac OS 13 MacBook Pro 15' 2017

Comment: You were supposed to improve the previous question you raised on the same subject and have it reopened, not open a new one. Welcome to Ask Different.

Comment: @Andy Griffiths I apologise, I'm new to Stack Exchange. In the title of the old post it said "[closed]" so I thought it was removed due to clarify. Should I remove this one and adjust the old post? Sorry for duplicating

Comment: What do you mean with „I have installed a file onto my external hard disk“? What kind of file, what did you install? How does this file relate to the problems you see with copying data *from* that disk? Also, what kind of filesystem is in the disk (APFS, NTFS, FAT)?

Comment: We can keep this question here, but please **edit** it to address the issues raised in the comments both here and below the original question.

Comment: This is very unlikely related to a corrupted drive.  You’re conflating the *coincidence* of you copying a file with [the drive failing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/296316/119271). When you get an error unmounting a drive, it’s not file related.

Comment: @nohillside I have transferred a big sound library (nki file) into the external drive. The external drive file system is FAT. Also I am not too sure that the file is relating to the problem, I have never had a problem with the external drive and transferring the file into the hard drive is the most recent thing I used it for before I had this issue.

Comment: @everyone Also I want to thank everyone who has commented for your support. It is really appreciated :)

Comment: FAT filesystem gets slower as more and more files in a folder - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52821728/fatfs-significant-slow-down-in-directories-with-many-files - perhaps that is also an issue?